# Maximum Likelihood Stopping Tolerance

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I have a large scale problem that I am training with MLE. It is taking quite a long time. I would like to set a stopping condition.

How does one set a tolerance level in MLE optimization?

1. absolute change in logL < tolerance
2. absolute change in logL/number_of_samples < tolerance
3. %change in LogL < tolerance

Obviously one can always go with any of them, but which one actually indicates that the change in model is small (at least under some well founded interpretation)?

For example (1) ignores sample size hence a fixed tolerance will not make much sense. (2) has some interpretation from KL sense, as average number of bits.

Comment: Option (3) is meaningless, because the log likelihood is defined only up to an additive constant.  Did you perhaps mean to write "% change in L" itself?

Comment: I have a similar problem, that I didnt resolve yet. But notice that loglikehood is actually defined up to constant, since the original likelhood can be multiplied by any number. That means that the ratio of log does not make big sense. 1000001 vs 1000000 is the same as 1 vs 0 in terms of logarithms.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than looking at the log likelihood alone, the most "rigorous" stopping criteria should be the gradient norm being small enough. Note that the gradient being zero is literally what we want mathematically (consider solving the maximisation problem by hand), while the change in the log likelihood between steps being small is just a heuristic for algorithmic purpose.

If the log-likelihood surface is very flat then in some neighbourhood of the MLE the change of function value between optimisation steps can be rather small. Any of your criteria may stop too early when the likelihood surface is almost flat, but an algorithm that insists on using only the gradient norm may make a lot of small improvement until it has found the location where the gradient norm is near zero; and sometimes these small steps accumulatively move the parameter quite a lot.

This also makes intuitive sense: the gradient approximates the change in $\log L$ when $\theta$ is moved *by an unit amount*. If moving $\theta$ by an unit amount will move $\log L$ a lot, then it is a bad idea to stop even if the next step will only give you a slight improvement. On the other hand, stopping when the change in log likelihood is small is equivalent to saying that "I will be happy if the log-likelihood is close enough to the maximum" while not caring where the true $\theta_{MLE}$ actually is. Note that the former is motivated by finding the exact location of the MLE while the latter is more similar to the cases, say, in finance: "if doing more computation will give me only $0.1\%$ improvement in my ~$100 investment return then it is fine; I really don't care about that one cent."

But log-likelihood is not dollars, and $0.1\%$ can be a lot. To see how important a 0.1% is, consider this: let an early-stopping algorithm stops at point $\theta_1$ with $\log L_1=-3001$ and another algorithm stops at $\theta_2$ with $\log L_2=-3000$. Note that $1/3000*100\% = 0.033\%$ only, but $L_2/L_1 = 2.718$. If we interpret the likelihood as the probability that the data occurs then the chance that the data occur if $\theta_2$ were true is more than twice if $\theta_1$ were true. Here one-third of a $0.1\%$ of improvement has led to the likelihood being double!

Comment: It seems to me the gradient is sensitive to the parameterization. E.g., if we were to change the units of measurement in a location problem from kilometers to meters, that would multiply the location parameter by 1000, thereby dividing the gradient by 1000 and changing a large gradient into a small one.  Since ultimately all analysis of the result will be based on comparing the optimal log likelihood to other values, there is a *universally applicable* tolerance for the log likelihood alone.  Often, finding it to within a tolerance of $0.1$ is more than good enough.

Comment: BTW, you err in your calculations: it is meaningless to divide one log likelihood by another.  You must *subtract* them to compare them.

Comment: Subtracting the two log-likelihood will give you one, so exp(1)=2.7 will be the ratio of the likelihood, not log likelihood. Regarding 0.1 as an universal tolerance I have to disagree. In some high dimensional problems I have seen some CG algorithm stops when each step move the log-lik only by 0.01 but the actual MLE differs from the stopping point by more than 10% or so in Euclidean norm. This is especially true for stuff like factor analysis or phylogenetics. Though I agree that the gradient is not scale invariant so even gradient-stopping require tuning.

Comment: The thing is, there's essentially no difference between a solution with a maximum log likelihood of $\Lambda$ and one with a maximum of $\Lambda-0.1.$ What you have observed and fixed your attention on, then, is a manifestation of *large uncertainty in the parameter estimates.*  It likely was not worth the extra computational effort to refine those estimates in the face of such uncertainty.

Comment: If the algorithm goes on ten more such steps then the ratio of the two likelihood will be 2.7. Whether it worths it is an entirely different thing: if all one wants is a point estimate then yes, the estimate “sucks anyway”. But if one is doing, say, a likelihood ratio test then this difference of 1 in the log-lik. is certainly not negligible because your critical value will usually come from a distribution that resembles the chi-square distribution. In practice, high uncertainty actually motivates doing this kind of a test…

Comment: Your first point is a good one: we have to understand the tolerance not in terms of differences in *successive* approximations, but in terms of an estimate of how close we might be to the optimum.

Comment: Your latest edit makes no sense, because *ratios* of log likelihoods are meaningless.

Comment: I had a typo. I have never written anything about the *ratios* of log likelihoods... The ratios of the *likelihood* is the difference of the two log-likelihoods passed to the exponential function. Please read carefully.

Comment: And the 0.033% is only an illustration to show exactly your point: the ratio of log likelihood is pointless. And because the stopping 0.1 stopping criteria is essentially claiming that 0.1 is small in the compared to 3000 (notice an implicit use of 0.1/3000 here in our intuition), the 0.1 stopping criteria is pointless.

Comment: You post still *explicitly* compares the *log* likelihood of $-3000$ to another *log* likelihood of $-3001$ using a ratio!  You can't rationally write one thing in your answer and then deny that in a comment.

Comment: I divided 1/3000 to show the ratio of *log* likelihood is absurd. I divided the *non-log* likelihoods to get that 2.7 to show that the ratio is of the *non-log* likelihood is big. Please read carefully.